# Collector must be more positive than the emitter

Tags: transistors, bjt

My book (The Art of Electronics by Paul Horowitz and Winfield Hill) is stating something that seems to be the opposite of the example it is using. I am not going to school for my studies so I apologize for having no go-to resources but here. Can anyone shed light on where I'm getting confused?

[image: NPN Transistor circuit]

I'll type out the relevant bits:

> A transistor is a 3-terminal device available in 2 flavors (npn and pnp),  with the properties that meet the following rules for npn transistors:
>
> 1. The collector must be more positive than the emitter.
> 2. ....
> 3. ....
> 4. When rules 1-3 are obeyed, IsubC is roughly proportional to IsubB and can be written as
>    IsubC = (hFE)(IsubB)
>    where hFE, the current gain (also called beta), is typically about 100.
>    ...
>
> When the switch is closed, the base rises to 0.6 volt (base-emitter diode is in forward conduction). The drop across the base resistor is 9.4 volts, so the base current is 9.4mA. Blind application of rule 4 gives IsubC - 940mA (for a typical beta of 100). This is wrong. Why? Because rule 4 holds only if rule 1 is obeyed; at a collector current of 100mA the lamp has 10 volts across it. To get a higher current you would have to pull the collector below ground.

---

Isn't the collector more positive than the emitter in this case? The collector has 10 volts and 100 mA. The emitter is literally connected to ground. The collector is therefore more positive than the emitter. Is it not?

Comment: A lamp voltage is a NOMINAL VALUE for use by a designer, as is the lamp current rating.   As a designer, you must use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they're saying is that *if* I<sub>C</sub> were 940mA *then* V<sub>E</sub> would have to be higher than V<sub>C</sub>. Since the voltage follows rule 1, I<sub>C</sub> *cannot* be 940mA.

Comment: Can you quickly explain your rationale behind "if IC were 940mA then VE would have to be higher than VC"?

Comment: 10V / 0.1A = 100ohm ... 940mA * 100ohm = 94V ... 10V - 94V = -84V ... -84V < 0V

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. Measuring the voltage across an LED I see 0. Maybe I didn't do it right. I would mark this as the correct answer, but  I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: You always have enough reputation to accept an answer, you just can't upvote until you have 15.

Comment: Indeed. I'm wrong once again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the switch is closed, the collector is at a few hundred mV in the example, not 10V.

The transistor stops having gain (Ic/Ib = HFE) as the collector voltage approaches zero.